# Why does powermail include css and jquery right after the installation of the extension?

Tags: jquery, typo3

Right after I downloaded and installed the Powermail (2.0.9) extension in the backend of TYPO3 4.7, files are loaded on my website (*www.africanfootprints.de*).

This happens even before adding Powermail to the static templates.

These CSS in the head:

```
typo3conf/ext/powermail/Resources/Public/Css/CssFancy.css
typo3conf/ext/powermail/Resources/Public/Css/jquery.ui.theme.css
typo3conf/ext/powermail/Resources/Public/Css/jquery.ui.datepicker.css
```

And these js at the end of the body:

```
typo3conf/ext/powermail/Resources/Public/Js/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js
typo3conf/ext/powermail/Resources/Public/Js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js
typo3conf/ext/powermail/Resources/Public/Js/jquery.validationEngine.js                          
typo3conf/ext/powermail/Resources/Public/Js/tabs.js
typo3conf/ext/powermail/Resources/Public/Js/powermail_frontend.js
typo3conf/ext/powermail/Resources/Public/Js/form.js
```

Since I just want the whole Powermail extension to load on the contact page I want t disable this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Typoscript to disable CSS and JS:

```
page {
# Inlude JavaScript files
includeJSFooterlibs {
    powermailJQuery = 
    powermailJQueryUi = 
    powermailJQueryUiDatepicker = 
    powermailJQueryFormValidationLanguage = 
    powermailJQueryFormValidation = 
    powermailJQueryTabs = 
}
includeJSFooter {
    powermailForm = 
}

# Include CSS files
includeCSS {
    powermailJQueryUiTheme = 
    powermailJQueryUiDatepicker = 
}
```

}

For more Typosrcipt possibilities see:

```
typo3conf/ext/powermail/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/setup.txt
```

Comment: Don't forget to copy the last curly brace outside the grey box

Comment: I recommend to us ">" instead of "=" after each item. So you really clear them from your TS.